# Postgres UDF functions C using fork

Tags: c, postgresql, unix, fork

I have developed one C UDF for postgres.
This UDF needs to invoke fork and run some function ( Does not invoke exec )
I am getting following error

```
LOG:  failed to find proc 0x7fb0715b95b0 in ProcArray
FATAL:  connection limit exceeded for non-superusers
```

I looked at some discussion at following link and looks like there was no conclusion. Can somebody let me know how I can run such UDF without causing above problem?

http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/108aqsaky6/fork-and-dynamically-loaded-c-functions

Comment: `fork()`ing without `exec` in a backend is likely to be an exceedingly bad idea. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: UDF uses one library which forks to run some JNI code. It does that because library is also used somewhere else and JNI does not allow creating/destroying JVM multiple times in a single process.

Comment: You mention JNI - does that mean you're using PL/Java?

Comment: No, UDF is written in C. Library that UDF uses makes some JNI call internally. Functions exported by this library are used by UDF.

Comment: This sounds likely to be quite unsafe to do within a PostgreSQL backend. Consider using listen and notify to trigger and an external process.